# "Уделить ваше внимание на то, что": корректность фразы

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, фразеология, выбор-слов

> Хотелось бы **уделить ваше внимание на то, что** главную роль в фильме играет начинающий актер.

Можно ли *уделять* **чье-то** внимание на что-то?  Есть ли грамматические ошибки в предложении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Замените "уделить" на "обратить"**, и всё будет хорошо.
*Обращать внимание — стараться привлечь внимание чье-л. к чему-л.*  (Идеографический словарь русского языка. — М.: Издательство ЭТС. Баранов О.С.. 1995). А уделить — значит *отдать, предоставить, выделив из чего-нибудь* (Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992). То есть **обратить** чьё-то внимание **на что-то** можно. **Уделяют** внимание **чему-то**.
В данном контексте, насколько я поняла, Вы именно обращаете внимание окружающих на этот факт, а не просите их уделить немножко своего внимания этому. В таком случае можно ещё **акцентировать или заострить внимание на том, что...**

Comment: Спасибо. Мои мысли схожи с вашими, однако составитель сборник заданий ЕГЭ, Сенина, считает иначе: тут должна быть ошибка, вызванная неправильным употреблением падежной формы местоимения.

Comment: Здесь одно местоимение — "ваше". Употреблено оно неправильно в связке с глаголом "уделить", уделить внимание можно **вам**, но тогда в этой фразе вообще нет смысла. Поэтому ошибка явно не в местоимении, а, судя по заданиям, в голове автора.

Comment: Позвольте,  Наталья, не согласиться, всё у Сениной верно: уделить ваше внимание (чему? Д.п.) на то(В..п), выбран неверный падеж  указательного местоимения ТО. А Вы какой частью речи считаете слово ТО?

Comment: Нужно читать задание внимательно, там же не написано заменить слово, там рекомендуют найти неверное употребление падежа местоимения, вот это и надо делать, а не критиковать автора тестов, у неё как раз огрехов почти нет.

Comment: Да, спасибо, Людмила, на ТО не обратила внимание, но это мало что меняет. На мой взгляд, именно "уделить внимание" здесь не подходит. Возможно, всё же стоило подумать над примером и выбрать что-то более подходящее, чем уделение внимания тому, что главная роль досталась молодому актёру. Я бы ещё поняла, если бы просили уделить внимание его игре в этом фильме... Само задание вышло неудачным.

Answer (score 2):

В старых словарях (напр. у Ушакова) можно встретить примеры "*уделения... на что-то*" (о выделении средств из бюджета) - видимо, так когда-то говорили, но не по поводу "внимания", тем более, чужого. Нельзя "уделить" *чужое* внимание ни чему-то, ни на что-то. Можно выразиться "**Хочется, чтобы вы уделили внимание тому-то**", но с простым фактом (актёр - начинающий) это не сочетается *стилистически*: "уделить внимание" значит "*отвести себе время на осмысление* чего-то или *что-то сделать в связи с этим*". Разумеется, "*обратить*" исправляет данную фразу (это о "направлении" внимания).